# Extracting data from splunk through java API(Servlets+HTML)

Tags: java, servlets, splunk

I am extracting data from *splunk* by following code:

```
Args outputArgs=new Args();
outputArgs.put("output_mode","csv");
InputStream stream=job.getResults(outputArgs);
int t=stream.available();
byte[] buffer= new byte[20000];
while(stream.read(buffer)!=-1)
{
  String a=new String(buffer);             
  PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
  String b[]=a.split("},");
  for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) 
  {
    out.print(b[i]);
  }
}
```

There are 300 events in *splunk* database. But here on executing the servlet it is showing only 150 events. Rest of the data or events are replaced by a black diamond symbol. I have checked the encoding options,but still the problem prevails.

Thanks in advance for your help.